# Loopback 4 use existing express server with loopback

Tags: express, loopback4

I have two server Loopback4 and express. Loopback's controllers are protected with loopback's jwt authentication and authorization.

Now I want to mount express server on loopback's server and use the same loopback's authentication for express server routes.

How to achieve this?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Loopback has a function `mountExpressRouter` that can mount the existing express server on loopback. here are docs https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Routes.html#mounting-an-express-router